# Pandas between() over 24 hour time range

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues with Pandas `between()` function.  I have `datetime.timestamp` values and am checking if times occur within a range of `datetime.time` values.

It works if my range `Start` time is less than `End` time within a given day.

```
import pandas as pd
dProd=[{ 'Time' : '2021-10-20 20:32:00'},
{'Time' : '2021-10-21 11:50:00'},
{'Time' : '2022-01-11 20:10:00'}]

dfProd = pd.DataFrame(dProd)
dfProd['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfProd['Time'])
dfProd['Pure_Time'] = dfProd['Time'].dt.time

dRange=[{'Start': '11:45', 'End' :'20:20'}]

dfRange = pd.DataFrame(dRange)
dfRange['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(dfRange['Start'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time
dfRange['End'] = pd.to_datetime(dfRange['End'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time

dfProd['Pure_Time'].between(dfRange['Start'].iloc[0],dfRange['End'].iloc[0])
```

Output is as I would expect, `between` works fine.

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
```

But if my time range goes "over the end of the day" nothing seems to ever return `True`

```
dRange=[{'Start': '20:00', 'End' :'2:00'}]

dfRange = pd.DataFrame(dRange)
dfRange['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(dfRange['Start'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time
dfRange['End'] = pd.to_datetime(dfRange['End'],format= '%H:%M' ).dt.time

dfProd['Pure_Time'].between(dfRange['Start'].iloc[0],dfRange['End'].iloc[0])
```

Output is always `False` for all values.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
```

I would expect `0` and `2` to be True as they are between `22:00` and `2:00` going "around" the 24 hour mark.  Is there a way to achieve this?  I understand no integer would ever be `between(4,-1)` but I would expect `datetime.time` to work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html). You will need to set your datetime64[ns] values to the Index, but then this allows for you to slice "over" the end of a day without issue. With this method you don't even need to create the 'Pure_Time' column.

```
dfProd.set_index('Time').between_time('20:00', '2:00')
#                    Pure_Time
#Time                         
#2021-10-20 20:32:00  20:32:00
#2022-01-11 20:10:00  20:10:00
```